# How to delete data from a database by API by using Axios in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, axios

How to delete the data from the database by using Axios and Vue JS, I tried to connect to it and only data like the method GET.
This is my code `remove(id) { Axios.delete('users/').then((result)=>{console.log('done')})`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your API is designed correctly enough, your delete endpoint would be `/users/{id}`. Thus you'd have to write:

```
remove(id) {
  return Axios.delete(`/users/${id}`).then(result => console.log("done"));
}
```

Comment: this is not working I got the error in the console 'DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8003/user/86 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: That just indicates there's no such route. Do you have a `DELETE` route setup, and if so is the path `/users/{id}`

Comment: No I don`t have such route, I tried the same path as you did write and got the same error as previously

Comment: Then it means you have to implement that endpoint

Comment: How do I need to do it?

Comment: That completely depends on what your API is written in

Comment: Do you mean about Axios?